# C++ reading file by line: hasNextLine?

Tags: c++, file, io, iteration

I am reading the contents of a file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char line[256];
ifstream infile(filename, ios::in);

if(infile){
    while (infile.getline(line, 256)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In the while-loop I want to do some things but only in all n-1 iterations, not in the very last iteration (line of the file)...so I thought of something like `infile.hasNextLine()` but unforunately I were not able to find something doing this.

How can this behaviour be achieved in C++?

Is counting the lines in the file the only way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated, but you rarely want to use the overload of `getline` that takes a pointer to char--you usually want `std::string line; while (std::getline(infile, line)) ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`peek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/?kw=peek):

```
if (infile.peek()!=EOF) 
   ...
```

If you have read the last line, there's nothing more to read and `peek()` will return `EOF`. Inversely, if `peek()` returns something else, it means that there is still data to read so a next line.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is doing what you want to do in the 2-n iterations and don't do it in the first iteration. I am guessing you want to do some stuff between two lines?

Comment: parsing line by line, coloring stuff, grouping lines by groups of two and doing some other stuff with it and finally I want some output on the console before the last line is read.